# get the connection info only from inifile

Tags: powerbuilder

I am a beginner at powerbuilder. I build application and i want to specify the connection info source for a login window only from inifile so the other ways be inactive. Here the code which is generated automatically by connection object wizard:

```
Choose Case is_connectfrom

    Case IS_USE_INIFILE                     /*  Populate Database Connection from INI file  */
        string ls_inifile = "C:\Users\3za\Documents\AA\pbtutor.ini"

        as_dbms         = ProfileString ( ls_inifile, "Database", "DBMS", "ODBC")
        as_database     = ProfileString ( ls_inifile, "Database", "Database", "")
        as_userid       = ProfileString ( ls_inifile, "Database", "UserID", "")
        as_dbpass       = ProfileString ( ls_inifile, "Database", "DBPass", "")
        as_logid            = ProfileString ( ls_inifile, "Database", "LogID", "")
        as_logpass      = ProfileString ( ls_inifile, "Database", "LogPassword",    "")
        as_server       = ProfileString ( ls_inifile, "Database", "Servername", "")
        as_dbparm       = ProfileString ( ls_inifile, "Database", "DBParm", "ConnectString='DSN=EAS Demo DB V125;UID=dba;PWD=sql'")
        as_lock         = ProfileString ( ls_inifile, "Database", "Lock", "")
        as_autocommit   = ProfileString ( ls_inifile, "Database", "AutoCommit", "false")

    Case IS_USE_REGISTRY                        /*  Populate Database Connection from Registry  */
        string ls_registrykey = "" + "\DataBase"

        If RegistryGet ( ls_registrykey, "DBMS",        RegString!, as_dbms ) <> 1 Then
            RegistrySet ( ls_registrykey, "DBMS",       RegString!, "ODBC" )
            RegistryGet ( ls_registrykey, "DBMS",       RegString!, as_dbms )
        End If
        If RegistryGet ( ls_registrykey, "Database",    RegString!, as_database ) <> 1 Then
            RegistrySet ( ls_registrykey, "Database",   RegString!, "" )
            RegistryGet ( ls_registrykey, "Database",   RegString!, as_database )
        End If
        If RegistryGet ( ls_registrykey, "UserID",      RegString!, as_userid ) <> 1 Then
            RegistrySet ( ls_registrykey, "UserID",         RegString!, "" )
            RegistryGet ( ls_registrykey, "UserID",         RegString!, as_userid )
        End If
        If RegistryGet ( ls_registrykey, "DBPass",      RegString!, as_dbpass ) <> 1 Then
            RegistrySet ( ls_registrykey, "DBPass",         RegString!, "" )
            RegistryGet ( ls_registrykey, "DBPass",         RegString!, as_dbpass )
        End If
        If RegistryGet ( ls_registrykey, "LogID",       RegString!, as_logid ) <> 1 Then
            RegistrySet ( ls_registrykey, "LogID",      RegString!, "" )
            RegistryGet ( ls_registrykey, "LogID",      RegString!, as_logid )
        End If
        If RegistryGet ( ls_registrykey, "LogPassword", RegString!, as_logpass ) <> 1 Then
            RegistrySet ( ls_registrykey, "LogPassword", RegString!, "" )
            RegistryGet ( ls_registrykey, "LogPassword", RegString!, as_logpass )
        End If
        If RegistryGet ( ls_registrykey, "Servername",  RegString!, as_server ) <> 1 Then
            RegistrySet ( ls_registrykey, "Servername",     RegString!, "" )
            RegistryGet ( ls_registrykey, "Servername",     RegString!, as_server )
        End If
        If RegistryGet ( ls_registrykey, "DBParm",      RegString!, as_dbparm ) <> 1 Then
            RegistrySet ( ls_registrykey, "DBParm",         RegString!, "ConnectString='DSN=EAS Demo DB V125;UID=dba;PWD=sql'" )
            RegistryGet ( ls_registrykey, "DBParm",         RegString!, as_dbparm )
        End If
        If RegistryGet ( ls_registrykey, "Lock",            RegString!, as_lock ) <> 1 Then
            RegistrySet ( ls_registrykey, "Lock",           RegString!, "" )
            RegistryGet ( ls_registrykey, "Lock",           RegString!, as_lock )
        End If
        If RegistryGet ( ls_registrykey, "AutoCommit",  RegString!, as_autocommit ) <> 1 Then
            RegistrySet ( ls_registrykey, "AutoCommit",     RegString!, "false" )
            RegistryGet ( ls_registrykey, "AutoCommit",     RegString!, as_autocommit )
        End If

    Case IS_USE_SCRIPT                          /*  Populate Database Connection from Script  */
        as_dbms         = "ODBC"
        as_database     = ""
        as_userid       = ""
        as_dbpass       = ""
        as_logid            = ""
        as_logpass      = ""
        as_server       = ""
        as_dbparm       = "ConnectString='DSN=EAS Demo DB V125;UID=dba;PWD=sql'"
        as_lock         = ""
        as_autocommit   = "false"


    Case Else

        Return -1

End Choose

Return 1
```

i try to make `IS_USE_REGISTRY` case and `IS_USE_SCRIPT` case as comments and the code is working normaly but still can't get the point how the compiler work.

Comment: If you want to get your settings from the ini file only, you can cut code for the other options. But what is exactly your problem / question?

Comment: OK, i get it there is no problem with my code , at first i thought that i must edit the connection info just from the inifile not from the powerbuilder script

Answer (score 0):

**Just replace ALL code above with this**:

```
string ls_inifile = "C:\Users\3za\Documents\AA\pbtutor.ini"

    as_dbms         = ProfileString ( ls_inifile, "Database", "DBMS", "ODBC")
    as_database     = ProfileString ( ls_inifile, "Database", "Database", "")
    as_userid       = ProfileString ( ls_inifile, "Database", "UserID", "")
    as_dbpass       = ProfileString ( ls_inifile, "Database", "DBPass", "")
    as_logid            = ProfileString ( ls_inifile, "Database", "LogID", "")
    as_logpass      = ProfileString ( ls_inifile, "Database", "LogPassword",    "")
    as_server       = ProfileString ( ls_inifile, "Database", "Servername", "")
    as_dbparm       = ProfileString ( ls_inifile, "Database", "DBParm", "ConnectString='DSN=EAS Demo DB V125;UID=dba;PWD=sql'")
    as_lock         = ProfileString ( ls_inifile, "Database", "Lock", "")
    as_autocommit   = ProfileString ( ls_inifile, "Database", "AutoCommit", "false")
```

This will load from INI all the time no matter what. It will populate your login window. If you wanted to log in automatically from the connection in ini than you'd have to skip calling the login window and manually code the connect using statement.